# Define "environment" in the context of truth tables

Tags: logic, definition

I'm looking at this site of MIT Open Courseware:
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/proofs/tp2-2/truth-tables-video/

I'm trying to understand the meaning of "environment" in the context of a truth table. Based on the site, I understand that an "environment" is something that determines if a proposition is True of False (the video states this at 50 seconds).

However, at 4:15 (in the video. 4 minutes and 15 seconds), the professor states that an environment is also the row of a truth table?

Correct me if my understanding of the video is wrong but is an "environment" both that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is both. A row on a truth table is the information about the logical value of the input propositions and the output proposition.
An environment is just specific values for the propositions.

Just for fun: the NOR(*NOT OR*) operator can construct every possible logical operator, such as AND, NOT, XOR, IF-THEN, etc.

Comment: I understand what you mean when you defined a row in a truth table. However, I don’t understand what you meant when you defined an environment. May you elaborate further? Also, that’s a cool fact! Thank you for sharing. I might need to know that in a pop quiz since I’m taking Computer Science.

Comment: The video says "Computer scientists call assignment of value to variables an environment". So, suppose you have two propositions $P$ and $Q$. _One_ environment could be that in which both are **true**. _Another_ environment could be that in which both are **false**. Looking at a specific row, you know what the values of the propositions are, so there is an environment there.

Comment: AHHHHH! That makes complete sense. An environment states if a proposition is True or False. Therefore, a row is also an environment since each row tells us the Truth assignment of each proposition. Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Thank you Sir! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can think of an 'environment' as a 'situation' or 'scenario' or 'possible state of affairs' ... which is exactly what rows in a truth-table represent